# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError in external java dependency inside the java dependency from Kotlin on Android 5

Tags: android, gradle, kotlin, java-8

I implement the external **JAVA**-dependency from the repository that contains another external dependency (**retro stream**) from the android application on Kotlin, as a result I get a crash on **android 5** by **java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method** according to the trace inside the **JAVA**-library (the trace is attached below). The problem occurs in the **Stream** class at the **retro stream** library (method "***of***"). I have checked that this library exist in external dependencies and all classes and methods are visible from the code, and, most interestingly, it does not crash on **android> = 7** devices.

I have tried to call method explicitly from the **kotlin** code - all ok.

```
Versions: 
Kotlin                   1.3.50 
Gradle plugin            3.4.2
Gradle                   5.4.1
Android studio           3.5
```

The problem code:

```java
    EmptyUtils.getLastNotNullGotValue(Supplier { "" })
```

> E/AndroidRuntime( 5699): FATAL EXCEPTION: main E/AndroidRuntime(
>   5699): Process: com.jetruby.kotlindslgradleexample, PID: 5699
>   E/AndroidRuntime( 5699): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method
>   of([Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava9/util/stream/Stream; in class
>   Ljava9/util/stream/Stream; or its super classes (declaration of
>   'java9.util.stream.Stream' appears in
>   /data/app/com.jetruby.kotlindslgradleexample-2/base.apk)
>   E/AndroidRuntime( 5699): at
>   ru.m4bank.mpos.service.network.utils.EmptyUtils.getLastNotNullGotValueOrDefault(EmptyUtils.java:40)
>   E/AndroidRuntime( 5699): at
>   ru.m4bank.mpos.service.network.utils.EmptyUtils.getLastNotNullGotValue(EmptyUtils.java:51)
>   E/AndroidRuntime( 5699): at
>   com.jetruby.kotlindslgradleexample.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:33)
>   E/AndroidRuntime( 5699): at
>   android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
>   E/AndroidRuntime( 5699): at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
>   E/AndroidRuntime( 5699): at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
>   E/AndroidRuntime( 5699): at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
>   E/AndroidRuntime( 5699): at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
>   E/AndroidRuntime( 5699): at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
>   E/AndroidRuntime( 5699): at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) E/AndroidRuntime(
>   5699): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) E/AndroidRuntime(
>   5699): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
>   E/AndroidRuntime( 5699): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native
>   Method) E/AndroidRuntime( 5699): at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) E/AndroidRuntime(
>   5699): at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
>   E/AndroidRuntime( 5699): at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)

Having experimented with various assembly options, I found that if you implement the **JAVA**-dependency locally (by file), there will be no crash on the **5-th android !!**. Also, the fall does not occur if compile from **JAVA**, and not from **kotlin**. And it falls only on **static methods in interfaces**.

In the picture below the are 2 dependency variants (the first I copied from the **gradle** cache when I pulled up the 2nd one and implement it locally as **file**, the second one just **pulled from the repository**).

[Implementation variants](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ORhU.png)

Results:

```
On android <7:  1-st variant - all ok, 2-nd variant - crashes.
On android >=7 - 1,2 variants - ok
```

I have decompiled the application and noticed that *from kotlin* **static methods from interfaces** are collected in a separate class (the auxiliary inner class **ClassName.CC** is created and static methods are placed in it). So, when implement dependencies **from the repository**, the decompiled external class refers to the **original class** and the original method, and when implement from the **local source** (copied from the pulled up repository to the libs folder), it refers to auxiliary **XX.CC**. There is a suspicion that is the reason of **java.lang.NoSuchMethodError crashes: No static method**.

[Decompiled classes of the problem class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TbNeI.png)

The code below is decompiled code of the "helper" class with the "missing" of method. It is the same for both successful and unsuccessful builds:

```java
    .class public final synthetic Ljava9/util/stream/Stream$-CC;
        .super Ljava/lang/Object;
        .source "Stream.java"


        # direct methods
        .method public static $default$dropWhile(Ljava9/util/stream/Stream;Ljava9/util/function/Predicate;)Ljava9/util/stream/Stream;
            .locals 3
            .param p0, "_this"    # Ljava9/util/stream/Stream;
            .annotation system Ldalvik/annotation/Signature;
                value = {
                    "(",
                    "Ljava9/util/function/Predicate<",
                    "-TT;>;)",
                    "Ljava9/util/stream/Stream<",
                    "TT;>;"
                }
            .end annotation

            .line 630
            .local p0, "this":Ljava9/util/stream/Stream;, "Ljava9/util/stream/Stream<TT;>;"
            .local p1, "predicate":Ljava9/util/function/Predicate;, "Ljava9/util/function/Predicate<-TT;>;"
            invoke-static {p1}, Ljava9/util/Objects;->requireNonNull(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;

            .line 633
            new-instance v0, Ljava9/util/stream/WhileOps$UnorderedWhileSpliterator$OfRef$Dropping;

            .line 634
            invoke-interface {p0}, Ljava9/util/stream/Stream;->spliterator()Ljava9/util/Spliterator;

            move-result-object v1

            const/4 v2, 0x1

            invoke-direct {v0, v1, v2, p1}, Ljava9/util/stream/WhileOps$UnorderedWhileSpliterator$OfRef$Dropping;-><init>(Ljava9/util/Spliterator;ZLjava9/util/function/Predicate;)V

            .line 635
            invoke-interface {p0}, Ljava9/util/stream/Stream;->isParallel()Z

            move-result v1

            .line 633
            invoke-static {v0, v1}, Ljava9/util/stream/StreamSupport;->stream(Ljava9/util/Spliterator;Z)Ljava9/util/stream/Stream;

            move-result-object v0

            .line 635
            invoke-static {p0}, Ljava9/util/stream/StreamSupport;->closeHandler(Ljava9/util/stream/BaseStream;)Ljava/lang/Runnable;

            move-result-object v1

            invoke-interface {v0, v1}, Ljava9/util/stream/Stream;->onClose(Ljava/lang/Runnable;)Ljava9/util/stream/BaseStream;

            move-result-object v0

            check-cast v0, Ljava9/util/stream/Stream;

            return-object v0
        .end method

        .method public static $default$takeWhile(Ljava9/util/stream/Stream;Ljava9/util/function/Predicate;)Ljava9/util/stream/Stream;
            .locals 3
            .param p0, "_this"    # Ljava9/util/stream/Stream;
            .annotation system Ldalvik/annotation/Signature;
                value = {
                    "(",
                    "Ljava9/util/function/Predicate<",
                    "-TT;>;)",
                    "Ljava9/util/stream/Stream<",
                    "TT;>;"
                }
            .end annotation

            .line 564
            .local p0, "this":Ljava9/util/stream/Stream;, "Ljava9/util/stream/Stream<TT;>;"
            .local p1, "predicate":Ljava9/util/function/Predicate;, "Ljava9/util/function/Predicate<-TT;>;"
            invoke-static {p1}, Ljava9/util/Objects;->requireNonNull(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;

            .line 567
            new-instance v0, Ljava9/util/stream/WhileOps$UnorderedWhileSpliterator$OfRef$Taking;

            .line 568
            invoke-interface {p0}, Ljava9/util/stream/Stream;->spliterator()Ljava9/util/Spliterator;

            move-result-object v1

            const/4 v2, 0x1

            invoke-direct {v0, v1, v2, p1}, Ljava9/util/stream/WhileOps$UnorderedWhileSpliterator$OfRef$Taking;-><init>(Ljava9/util/Spliterator;ZLjava9/util/function/Predicate;)V

            .line 569
            invoke-interface {p0}, Ljava9/util/stream/Stream;->isParallel()Z

            move-result v1

            .line 567
            invoke-static {v0, v1}, Ljava9/util/stream/StreamSupport;->stream(Ljava9/util/Spliterator;Z)Ljava9/util/stream/Stream;

            move-result-object v0

            .line 569
            invoke-static {p0}, Ljava9/util/stream/StreamSupport;->closeHandler(Ljava9/util/stream/BaseStream;)Ljava/lang/Runnable;

            move-result-object v1

            invoke-interface {v0, v1}, Ljava9/util/stream/Stream;->onClose(Ljava/lang/Runnable;)Ljava9/util/stream/BaseStream;

            move-result-object v0

            check-cast v0, Ljava9/util/stream/Stream;

            return-object v0
        .end method

        .method public static builder()Ljava9/util/stream/Stream$Builder;
            .locals 1
            .annotation system Ldalvik/annotation/Signature;
                value = {
                    "<T:",
                    "Ljava/lang/Object;",
                    ">()",
                    "Ljava9/util/stream/Stream$Builder<",
                    "TT;>;"
                }
            .end annotation

            .line 1148
            new-instance v0, Ljava9/util/stream/Streams$StreamBuilderImpl;

            invoke-direct {v0}, Ljava9/util/stream/Streams$StreamBuilderImpl;-><init>()V

            return-object v0
        .end method

        .method public static concat(Ljava9/util/stream/Stream;Ljava9/util/stream/Stream;)Ljava9/util/stream/Stream;
            .locals 3
            .annotation system Ldalvik/annotation/Signature;
                value = {
                    "<T:",
                    "Ljava/lang/Object;",
                    ">(",
                    "Ljava9/util/stream/Stream<",
                    "+TT;>;",
                    "Ljava9/util/stream/Stream<",
                    "+TT;>;)",
                    "Ljava9/util/stream/Stream<",
                    "TT;>;"
                }
            .end annotation

            .line 1387
            .local p0, "a":Ljava9/util/stream/Stream;, "Ljava9/util/stream/Stream<+TT;>;"
            .local p1, "b":Ljava9/util/stream/Stream;, "Ljava9/util/stream/Stream<+TT;>;"
            invoke-static {p0}, Ljava9/util/Objects;->requireNonNull(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;

            .line 1388
            invoke-static {p1}, Ljava9/util/Objects;->requireNonNull(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;

            .line 1391
            new-instance v0, Ljava9/util/stream/Streams$ConcatSpliterator$OfRef;

            .line 1392
            invoke-interface {p0}, Ljava9/util/stream/Stream;->spliterator()Ljava9/util/Spliterator;

            move-result-object v1

            invoke-interface {p1}, Ljava9/util/stream/Stream;->spliterator()Ljava9/util/Spliterator;

            move-result-object v2

            invoke-direct {v0, v1, v2}, Ljava9/util/stream/Streams$ConcatSpliterator$OfRef;-><init>(Ljava9/util/Spliterator;Ljava9/util/Spliterator;)V

            .line 1393
            .local v0, "split":Ljava9/util/Spliterator;, "Ljava9/util/Spliterator<TT;>;"
            invoke-interface {p0}, Ljava9/util/stream/Stream;->isParallel()Z

            move-result v1

            if-nez v1, :cond_1

            invoke-interface {p1}, Ljava9/util/stream/Stream;->isParallel()Z

            move-result v1

            if-eqz v1, :cond_0

            goto :goto_0

            :cond_0
            const/4 v1, 0x0

            goto :goto_1

            :cond_1
            :goto_0
            const/4 v1, 0x1

            :goto_1
            invoke-static {v0, v1}, Ljava9/util/stream/StreamSupport;->stream(Ljava9/util/Spliterator;Z)Ljava9/util/stream/Stream;

            move-result-object v1

            .line 1394
            .local v1, "stream":Ljava9/util/stream/Stream;, "Ljava9/util/stream/Stream<TT;>;"
            invoke-static {p0, p1}, Ljava9/util/stream/Streams;->composedClose(Ljava9/util/stream/BaseStream;Ljava9/util/stream/BaseStream;)Ljava/lang/Runnable;

            move-result-object v2

            invoke-interface {v1, v2}, Ljava9/util/stream/Stream;->onClose(Ljava/lang/Runnable;)Ljava9/util/stream/BaseStream;

            move-result-object v2

            check-cast v2, Ljava9/util/stream/Stream;

            return-object v2
        .end method

        .method public static empty()Ljava9/util/stream/Stream;
            .locals 2
            .annotation system Ldalvik/annotation/Signature;
                value = {
                    "<T:",
                    "Ljava/lang/Object;",
                    ">()",
                    "Ljava9/util/stream/Stream<",
                    "TT;>;"
                }
            .end annotation

            .line 1158
            invoke-static {}, Ljava9/util/Spliterators;->emptySpliterator()Ljava9/util/Spliterator;

            move-result-object v0

            const/4 v1, 0x0

            invoke-static {v0, v1}, Ljava9/util/stream/StreamSupport;->stream(Ljava9/util/Spliterator;Z)Ljava9/util/stream/Stream;

            move-result-object v0

            return-object v0
        .end method

        .method public static generate(Ljava9/util/function/Supplier;)Ljava9/util/stream/Stream;
            .locals 3
            .annotation system Ldalvik/annotation/Signature;
                value = {
                    "<T:",
                    "Ljava/lang/Object;",
                    ">(",
                    "Ljava9/util/function/Supplier<",
                    "+TT;>;)",
                    "Ljava9/util/stream/Stream<",
                    "TT;>;"
                }
            .end annotation

            .line 1345
            .local p0, "s":Ljava9/util/function/Supplier;, "Ljava9/util/function/Supplier<+TT;>;"
            invoke-static {p0}, Ljava9/util/Objects;->requireNonNull(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;

            .line 1346
            new-instance v0, Ljava9/util/stream/StreamSpliterators$InfiniteSupplyingSpliterator$OfRef;

            const-wide v1, 0x7fffffffffffffffL

            invoke-direct {v0, v1, v2, p0}, Ljava9/util/stream/StreamSpliterators$InfiniteSupplyingSpliterator$OfRef;-><init>(JLjava9/util/function/Supplier;)V

            const/4 v1, 0x0

            invoke-static {v0, v1}, Ljava9/util/stream/StreamSupport;->stream(Ljava9/util/Spliterator;Z)Ljava9/util/stream/Stream;

            move-result-object v0

            return-object v0
        .end method

        .method public static iterate(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava9/util/function/Predicate;Ljava9/util/function/UnaryOperator;)Ljava9/util/stream/Stream;
            .locals 8
            .annotation system Ldalvik/annotation/Signature;
                value = {
                    "<T:",
                    "Ljava/lang/Object;",
                    "S:TT;>(TS;",
                    "Ljava9/util/function/Predicate<",
                    "TS;>;",
                    "Ljava9/util/function/UnaryOperator<",
                    "TS;>;)",
                    "Ljava9/util/stream/Stream<",
                    "TT;>;"
                }
            .end annotation

            .line 1287
            .local p0, "seed":Ljava/lang/Object;, "TS;"
            .local p1, "hasNext":Ljava9/util/function/Predicate;, "Ljava9/util/function/Predicate<TS;>;"
            .local p2, "next":Ljava9/util/function/UnaryOperator;, "Ljava9/util/function/UnaryOperator<TS;>;"
            invoke-static {p2}, Ljava9/util/Objects;->requireNonNull(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;

            .line 1288
            invoke-static {p1}, Ljava9/util/Objects;->requireNonNull(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;

            .line 1289
            new-instance v7, Ljava9/util/stream/Stream$2;

            const-wide v1, 0x7fffffffffffffffL

            const/16 v3, 0x410

            move-object v0, v7

            move-object v4, p2

            move-object v5, p0

            move-object v6, p1

            invoke-direct/range {v0 .. v6}, Ljava9/util/stream/Stream$2;-><init>(JILjava9/util/function/UnaryOperator;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava9/util/function/Predicate;)V

            .line 1331
            .local v0, "spliterator":Ljava9/util/Spliterator;, "Ljava9/util/Spliterator<TT;>;"
            const/4 v1, 0x0

            invoke-static {v0, v1}, Ljava9/util/stream/StreamSupport;->stream(Ljava9/util/Spliterator;Z)Ljava9/util/stream/Stream;

            move-result-object v1

            return-object v1
        .end method

        .method public static iterate(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava9/util/function/UnaryOperator;)Ljava9/util/stream/Stream;
            .locals 7
            .annotation system Ldalvik/annotation/Signature;
                value = {
                    "<T:",
                    "Ljava/lang/Object;",
                    "S:TT;>(TS;",
                    "Ljava9/util/function/UnaryOperator<",
                    "TS;>;)",
                    "Ljava9/util/stream/Stream<",
                    "TT;>;"
                }
            .end annotation

            .line 1224
            .local p0, "seed":Ljava/lang/Object;, "TS;"
            .local p1, "f":Ljava9/util/function/UnaryOperator;, "Ljava9/util/function/UnaryOperator<TS;>;"
            invoke-static {p1}, Ljava9/util/Objects;->requireNonNull(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;

            .line 1225
            new-instance v6, Ljava9/util/stream/Stream$1;

            const-wide v1, 0x7fffffffffffffffL

            const/16 v3, 0x410

            move-object v0, v6

            move-object v4, p1

            move-object v5, p0

            invoke-direct/range {v0 .. v5}, Ljava9/util/stream/Stream$1;-><init>(JILjava9/util/function/UnaryOperator;Ljava/lang/Object;)V

            .line 1244
            .local v0, "spliterator":Ljava9/util/Spliterator;, "Ljava9/util/Spliterator<TT;>;"
            const/4 v1, 0x0

            invoke-static {v0, v1}, Ljava9/util/stream/StreamSupport;->stream(Ljava9/util/Spliterator;Z)Ljava9/util/stream/Stream;

            move-result-object v1

            return-object v1
        .end method

        .method public static of(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava9/util/stream/Stream;
            .locals 2
            .annotation system Ldalvik/annotation/Signature;
                value = {
                    "<T:",
                    "Ljava/lang/Object;",
                    ">(TT;)",
                    "Ljava9/util/stream/Stream<",
                    "TT;>;"
                }
            .end annotation

            .line 1169
            .local p0, "t":Ljava/lang/Object;, "TT;"
            new-instance v0, Ljava9/util/stream/Streams$StreamBuilderImpl;

            invoke-direct {v0, p0}, Ljava9/util/stream/Streams$StreamBuilderImpl;-><init>(Ljava/lang/Object;)V

            const/4 v1, 0x0

            invoke-static {v0, v1}, Ljava9/util/stream/StreamSupport;->stream(Ljava9/util/Spliterator;Z)Ljava9/util/stream/Stream;

            move-result-object v0

            return-object v0
        .end method

        .method public static varargs of([Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava9/util/stream/Stream;
            .locals 1
            .annotation system Ldalvik/annotation/Signature;
                value = {
                    "<T:",
                    "Ljava/lang/Object;",
                    ">([TT;)",
                    "Ljava9/util/stream/Stream<",
                    "TT;>;"
                }
            .end annotation

            .line 1196
            .local p0, "values":[Ljava/lang/Object;, "[TT;"
            invoke-static {p0}, Ljava9/util/J8Arrays;->stream([Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava9/util/stream/Stream;

            move-result-object v0

            return-object v0
        .end method

        .method public static ofNullable(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava9/util/stream/Stream;
            .locals 2
            .annotation system Ldalvik/annotation/Signature;
                value = {
                    "<T:",
                    "Ljava/lang/Object;",
                    ">(TT;)",
                    "Ljava9/util/stream/Stream<",
                    "TT;>;"
                }
            .end annotation

            .line 1183
            .local p0, "t":Ljava/lang/Object;, "TT;"
            if-nez p0, :cond_0

            invoke-static {}, Ljava9/util/stream/Stream$-CC;->empty()Ljava9/util/stream/Stream;

            move-result-object v0

            goto :goto_0

            :cond_0
            new-instance v0, Ljava9/util/stream/Streams$StreamBuilderImpl;

            invoke-direct {v0, p0}, Ljava9/util/stream/Streams$StreamBuilderImpl;-><init>(Ljava/lang/Object;)V

            const/4 v1, 0x0

            .line 1184
            invoke-static {v0, v1}, Ljava9/util/stream/StreamSupport;->stream(Ljava9/util/Spliterator;Z)Ljava9/util/stream/Stream;

            move-result-object v0

            :goto_0
            return-object v0
        .end method
```

The decompiled method of the **JAVA**-library in that the absent method is called (**Build with crash**):

```java
    .method public static varargs getLastNotNullValue([Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
        .locals 2
        .annotation system Ldalvik/annotation/Signature;
            value = {
                "<T:",
                "Ljava/lang/Object;",
                ">([TT;)TT;"
            }
        .end annotation

        .annotation runtime Ljava/lang/SafeVarargs;
        .end annotation

        .line 56
        .local p0, "values":[Ljava/lang/Object;, "[TT;"
        invoke-static {p0}, Ljava9/util/stream/Stream;->of([Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava9/util/stream/Stream;

        move-result-object v0

        sget-object v1, Lru/m4bank/mpos/service/network/utils/-$$Lambda$h24iVvNNOyPAWTyqI3I8dzCunHY;->INSTANCE:Lru/m4bank/mpos/service/network/utils/-$$Lambda$h24iVvNNOyPAWTyqI3I8dzCunHY;

        invoke-interface {v0, v1}, Ljava9/util/stream/Stream;->filter(Ljava9/util/function/Predicate;)Ljava9/util/stream/Stream;

        move-result-object v0

        invoke-interface {v0}, Ljava9/util/stream/Stream;->findFirst()Ljava9/util/Optional;

        move-result-object v0

        sget-object v1, Lru/m4bank/mpos/service/network/utils/-$$Lambda$EmptyUtils$2lJJnncNhWO5-cW1nB8g96aMo4M;->INSTANCE:Lru/m4bank/mpos/service/network/utils/-$$Lambda$EmptyUtils$2lJJnncNhWO5-cW1nB8g96aMo4M;

        invoke-virtual {v0, v1}, Ljava9/util/Optional;->orElseGet(Ljava9/util/function/Supplier;)Ljava/lang/Object;

        move-result-object v0

        return-object v0
    .end method
```

The same decompiled method (**Build without crash**):

```java
    .method public static varargs getLastNotNullValue([Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
        .locals 2
        .annotation system Ldalvik/annotation/Signature;
            value = {
                "<T:",
                "Ljava/lang/Object;",
                ">([TT;)TT;"
            }
        .end annotation

        .annotation runtime Ljava/lang/SafeVarargs;
        .end annotation

        .line 56
        .local p0, "values":[Ljava/lang/Object;, "[TT;"
        invoke-static {p0}, Ljava9/util/stream/Stream$-CC;->of([Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava9/util/stream/Stream;

        move-result-object v0

        sget-object v1, Lru/m4bank/mpos/service/network/utils/-$$Lambda$h24iVvNNOyPAWTyqI3I8dzCunHY;->INSTANCE:Lru/m4bank/mpos/service/network/utils/-$$Lambda$h24iVvNNOyPAWTyqI3I8dzCunHY;

        invoke-interface {v0, v1}, Ljava9/util/stream/Stream;->filter(Ljava9/util/function/Predicate;)Ljava9/util/stream/Stream;

        move-result-object v0

        invoke-interface {v0}, Ljava9/util/stream/Stream;->findFirst()Ljava9/util/Optional;

        move-result-object v0

        sget-object v1, Lru/m4bank/mpos/service/network/utils/-$$Lambda$EmptyUtils$2lJJnncNhWO5-cW1nB8g96aMo4M;->INSTANCE:Lru/m4bank/mpos/service/network/utils/-$$Lambda$EmptyUtils$2lJJnncNhWO5-cW1nB8g96aMo4M;

        invoke-virtual {v0, v1}, Ljava9/util/Optional;->orElseGet(Ljava9/util/function/Supplier;)Ljava/lang/Object;

        move-result-object v0

        return-object v0
    .end method
```

Question: is it a **kotlin** bug or am I doing something wrong, and how then can I use the **JAVA**-libraries **from the repository** (which contain **interfaces with static methods** inside) on **android <7** and don't crash?

Comment: Unfortunately, from your description, I didn't really understand what you are doing here.

Comment: Did you set `compileKotlin.kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"`?

Comment: The `getLastNotNullValue` bytecode you show has obviously not gone through Android R8 desugaring. Any chance you are using Instant Run or an outdated AS version?

Comment: @Satorius, Yes,  I have checked that use it.                                        
        `compileOptions {
        setSourceCompatibility(JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8)
        setTargetCompatibility(JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8)
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        val options = this as? KotlinJvmOptions
        options?.jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8.toString()
    }`

Comment: @apophis, I have tryed from command line and used d8 and r8. The same result `android.enableR8=true
android.enableR8.libraries=true`

Comment: Don't know what's going wrong, but `/Stream;->of(` instead of `/Stream$-CC;->of(` seems to suggest that the class file hasn't been desugared.

Comment: I assume that the key moment is that i implement dependency **by repo**. **Stream.of** is called inside the **JAVA**-dependency. If I call it from code - all will be ok, and if I download dependency and implement locally all will be ok. Why desugaring is maked in first case and isn't maked in second?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have faced with this problem (After upgrade the **Android Gradle Plugin** version to **4+**) again and have had to solve it by my own.

**After investigation I find where was the problem:**

1. All my dependencies were artifacts -> it doesn't have metadata.
2. **Android Studio** assembles an apk not the same way as in the console (It adds options for **API** level during the assembling process via run button to speed up) -> **android 7+** devices work only because target **API** was **24+** and the desugaring for static methods in interfaces wasn't made.
3. Java version works due to different desugaring and dependency caching mechanism (Stopped to work after updating **Android Gradle Plugin** to **4+**).
4. About local dependency: I assume that it worked because gradle doesn't cache it and have to recompile.

**Solution**
I have added a proper metadata (**pom.xml** or **.module** files) to my dependencies which marks binary files dependencies graph explicitly and now **R8** makes proper desugaring and everything is OK now.

**P. S.**
It works if all dependencies will be implemented locally but it looks more like workaround.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use **Java Stream** Api in Android API level < 24 which is not possible.

Check what you can and can't use based on Android API level [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/features/java8-support.html#supported_features)

Comment: Nonsense. He's using a [backport](https://github.com/retrostreams/android-retrostreams) of the Stream API that is targeted to API Level < 24. Does work fine, at least when used from Java.